# Datatables AJAX Data Source and Custom Pagination actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable, pagination

I am using Datatables for building the table for my data.

I am passing JSON response from Server side [Java] to JSP and using Datatables js to build the tables in JSP using the same data.

`If I pass 100 records, Datatables automatically provides facility to paginate and scroll through the results. But in my case, I always get only 20 records and when I user click on next page, I should call the localServlet to fetch fresh JSON response for next 20records.`

So how do I configure Datatable so that whenever pagination function is used, call the AJAX resource and fetch the data and paint it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a sample at http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

however the code is in PHP.  But having a look at it you will see that there request parameters it uses are `iDisplayStart` and `iDisplayLength`

You will have to reimplement this in your server side java.

Below is some code I have used (using Stripes)

```
    Long count = (Long) getContext().getRequest().getSession(true).getAttribute("xbcount");
    if (count == null) {
        count = histDao.getCount();
        getContext().getRequest().getSession(true).setAttribute("xbcount", count);
    }

    DataTableRes res = new DataTableRes (getsEcho(), count, count);

    int rowStartIdxAndCount[] = {getiDisplayStart(), getiDisplayLength()};

    List<HistoryUint> list = histDao.findAll(rowStartIdxAndCount);
```

And the DAO

```
public List<HistoryUint> findAll(final int... rowStartIdxAndCount) {
    EntityManagerHelper.log("finding all HistoryUint instances",
            Level.INFO, null);
    try {
        final String queryString = "select model from HistoryUint model";
        Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(queryString);
        if (rowStartIdxAndCount != null && rowStartIdxAndCount.length > 0) {
            int rowStartIdx = Math.max(0, rowStartIdxAndCount[0]);
            if (rowStartIdx > 0) {
                query.setFirstResult(rowStartIdx);
            }

            if (rowStartIdxAndCount.length > 1) {
                int rowCount = Math.max(0, rowStartIdxAndCount[1]);
                if (rowCount > 0) {
                    query.setMaxResults(rowCount);
                }
            }
        }
        return query.getResultList();
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        EntityManagerHelper.log("find all failed", Level.SEVERE, re);
        throw re;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have seen some other tutorials, but nothing is close enough

Comment: SOrry I think you misundersood. This is my JSON Data http://pastebin.com/keLpYy1J
and this is my javascript in jsp http://pastebin.com/Uzp332Lj

I couldn't understand how to get inner data [JSON element.innerElement.value]